# Xamarin.iOS MessagingRemoteException: Build1660001055

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build1660001055 while executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/16.6.0.1055/execute-task/CBREApp.iOS/e6f82e0002fCopy
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Copy' threw an exception.
PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.

Comment: From the discussion in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/961282/xamarinios-fails-to-build-with-messagingremoteexce.html).  A fix for this issue is now available in preview release. Try out the fix by installing the most recent preview from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/).

Answer (score 0):

If you were like me who did not want to install the 16.7 Preview release just to get past this bug, the fix for this issue has luckily been released today (June 1st 2020) as part of update 16.6.1: [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.6.1)

Bug Report Link: [xamarinios-fails-to-build-with-messagingremoteexce](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/961282/xamarinios-fails-to-build-with-messagingremoteexce.html)

(Note that as per this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1043449/typeinitializationexception-the-type-initializer-f.html), a temporary work around for this bug was to delete or change the build action of the `iTunesArtwork@1x.png` and `iTunesArtwork@2x.png` in your iOS project)